# find part of URL in all field (elasticsearch)

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have the following mapping:

```
"urls": {
   "type": "string", 
   "index_name": "url", 
   "boost": "1",
   "analyzer": "aurlemail",
   "store": "yes"
 }
```

and the analyzer defined as following:

```
index.analysis.analyzer.aurlemail:
  type: custom
  tokenizer: uax_url_email
  filter: lowercase, fngramurl

index.analysis.filter.fngramurl:
  type: nGram
  min_gram: 3
  max_gram: 20
```

and I have `http://www.google.com` and `http://www.google.com/hugo` added to the index, two separate documents.

when I perform a `termQuery` on the specific field I get the expected hits (e.g. I search for `www.google.com`, or `google.com`), but when I just want a simple query, where I don't define any fields I get zero results.

the code looks like this:

```
client().prepareSearch("myindex").setQuery("www.google.com")
  .execute().actionGet();
```

How do I get the results without having to specify a `termQuery`, the specific field respectively?

**update**

more specific: I want to receive the hits also when I just query for *google*, or even *com*. This should be available in the index, due to the defined analyzer (I suppose), but neither a `matchQuery` nor a `stringQuery` work as expected

**update 2**

the version of ES in question is 1.1.0

Comment: try one thing.. remove all analyzer and use the default one anf use the match query.. It will definitely work..

Comment: unfortunately no luck. but i'll take it as granted, as long as I can find the complete domain name within an url (thanks to your answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use query string queries with default field as "_all".

```
client().prepareSearch("myindex").setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryString("www.google.com")
.defaultField("_all")).execute().actionGet();
```

**Update**

*Match query*

```
 client().prepareSearch("myindex").setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("_all", "google")).execute().actionGet();
```

Hope it helps..!

Comment: it works for "www.google.com", but not for only "google"..which should match as well, as I'd suppose?

Comment: I don't think it will work..  For tat u need to change in analyzer

Comment: thanks for the update. <code>matchQuery</code> doesn't work either unfortunately, i'll check the analyzer what other options I have.